# DynamoHttpServletRequest.getRemotePort() is return 0 How to get client Remort Port

Tags: java, servlets, request, atg, atg-dynamo

I need client remote port for some validation. I tried to get Remote Port in request but result come only Zero 0. I seen that OOTB class DynamoHttpServletRequest its default return the zero any way to get the client remote port.

In OOTB class DynamoHttpServletRequest returns

```
public int getRemotePort() {
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any possibility to get remote port?
Any alternative ways to get Client Remote port?

Comment: DynamoHttpServletRequest provides access to server's implementation of HttpServletRequest (by getRequest() method). Have you tried accessing remote port directly from there?

Comment: thank you now i got the remote port of the client. After try this DynamoHttpServletRequest.getRequest().getRemotePort() i got it.

Comment: @pantuptus i have small clarification is there any possibility to get a constant remote port for the client. its look like session if user enter into the site the browser created a client port that port only destroy when user closed the connection until i need same port for hole request (not every request response time port change). is there any possibilities ?

Comment: I don't get your question. Are you developing on client side or server side? If server side, then its not your job to influence the port that the client is requesting you.

Comment: @pantuptus i am try to do some validation token for security purpose to avoid the bots create a request. Am create a token with client port and set in the session after some request only i get the client port and session set client port also same mean valid request check.

Comment: Still not clear. You expect that client is requesting your app always with the same port during a particular session. But on the other hand, you observe that it is not a rule. So why do you still want to validate that?

Comment: Because of if user enter into the app that time i fetch the remote port form request and set in session. Form submission time i fetch the remote port to validate stored session remote port and current request remote port is same mean i am allow to submit the form. main reason some of the form are submitted by bots without valid data. i tried re-captcha validation that also some time failed. So I validate the user-agent and remote port with re-captcha it will help to avoid from bots. that's only i need client remote port but each and every request port number is change so any alternative ways

Comment: Then I don't think you should validate against remotePort. See my comment to the other question you asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64641731/how-to-get-a-user-clinet-remote-port-in-java-dynamohttpservletrequest.

Answer (score 0):

I got the remote port help of implemented class HttpServletRequest.

```
public int getClientPort(DynamoHttpServletRequest req){ 
    int remortPortVal = req.getRequest().getRemotePort();
    return remortPortVal;
}
```